# Get rid of .NET unreleased tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The following tags should be burninated.

- [.net-4.0-rc1](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-rc1)
- [.net-4.0-beta](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-beta)

As of April 12, 2010, The .NET 4.0 Framework has been [released](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:.NET_Framework_version_history). There is no value for keeping these tags around. There are basically two possibilities:

1. The subject of the question made it into the framework (no longer beta or rc). In this case, the [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) tag would make perfect sense, and the question should be retagged.
2. The subject of the question didn't make it into the framework. In this case, the question doesn't provide any value to future users/readers.

Regardless of the situation, these tags don't provide any additional value to anyone.

Comment: The [.net-4.0-beta] has no questions associated with it, and will get cleaned up in the nightly processing.  The other one only has 8 questions associated with it.  Whether or not it should be removed, I don't know; maybe the question is *only* valid to that version of .NET.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[.net-4.0-beta](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-beta) has 0 questions tagged to it; it will end up being deleted soon enough automatically.

[.net-4.0-rc1](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-rc1) has 8 questions tagged to it.  That's a small enough number that you can just retag those 8 questions on your own; there's no need to post a meta question and have any official support.

If a question is no longer applicable (i.e. the question is only useful to the rc1, and not to the released 4.0, then it's "too localized" and you can flag or vote to close accordingly.  If it's not, then the retag to .NET-4.0 would be appropriate, as you described.